# Sense a time range in a text string, using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to be able to find time ranges within a string using a regex and then wrap them in a < span >. The time ranges will be formatted like this:

`Hello, I would like to meet between 9:00-12:00 but also 1:00-6:00 would work for me. Thank you.`

I would like the final output to be:

`Hello, I would like to meet between <span>9:00-12:00</span> but also <span>1:00-6:00</span> would work for me. Thank you.`

Comment: How strict can we assume the formatting to be? Would `between 08:00-12:00 but also 1:00 -6:00` be valid, for example?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432104/jquery-wrap-div-around-time-ranges

Answer (score 2):

```
mystring.replace(/(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\-\d{1,2}\:\d{2})/g,"<span>$1</span>")
```

presto! super dangerous stuff though.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and adding that it is potentially a Bad Thing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - It's not a bad thing for the requirement presented in the question: OP is talking about processing "a string", they're not attempting to parse html with regex.

Comment: for further reading, my favorite blogpost on how regexp parsing is a good but a bad thing as well: http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2010/02/hashtag-standards/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
var str = "your string here...";

str = str.replace(/(\d\d?:\d\d-\d\d?:\d\d)/g,"<span>$1</span>");
```

`\d` matches *any* digit though, so the above accepts "times" like `99:99` - you might like to narrow it down to the appropriate number ranges. Perhaps something like:

```
/((1[0-2]|\d):[0-5]\d-(1[0-2]|\d):[0-5]\d)/g
```